# How can I get the azure devops organisation name from an azure devops app?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Is there a way (via APIs) to get the organisation ID from an installed azure app?

I currently have an `authorization_token` via a request to the [oauth2/v2.0/token endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-client_secret).

With the scope `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default`

Comment: Organization ID is the `tenantID` of your Azure AD tenant where your Azure application is registered. As you already have token, you can simply decode it by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and find `tid` claim like [this](https://i.imgur.com/e8TUuVG.png).

Comment: Hello @Sridevi - I have tried replacing the ORG_NAME with the uuid you mentioned and it is not working (the fallback html login page)

https://dev.azure.com/ORG_NAME/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.0

Comment: `OrganizationID` is different and your Azure DevOps Organization name is different.

Comment: ahh sorry I meant azure devops organization name!

Answer (score 0):

To get DevOps **Organization name**, you can call below DevOps API by passing **user identityID** in `memberId` like below:

```http
GET https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/accounts?memberId=<user identityID>&api-version=7.1-preview.1
Authorization: Bearer <authorization_token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

For **Organization ID**, you can call below **DevOps API** with your existing  *authorization_token* and check for **`Domain $value`** in response  like below:

```http
GET vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization_name}/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue=<Azure AD user UPN>&queryMembership=None&api-version=7.0
Authorization: Bearer <authorization_token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Where do I get `<user ObjectID>`? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Ahh okay - there is no way via the `authorization_token` ?

Comment: You can call second DevOps API call I mentioned in answer to get **Organization ID** in which <user identityID> also comes in `id` of response.

Comment: Yeah but the second API call i need the Organization ID which is what i need in the first place :)

Comment: You need to have the **organization name** at least once to get <user identityID> from which you can fetch all DevOps Organization names that the user is a member of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254057/discussion-between-sridevi-and-maxisme).